# <li> mouse hover background

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a code like this. But the background, that changes, doesn't touches the left border of the div. How can I do this without changing the position of the text ('Element 1')?

CSS:

```
    li{
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    li:hover{
        background: green;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 200px;">
    <ul>
        <li>Element 1</li>
        <li>Element 2</li>
        <li>Element 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F698P/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set padding of `ul` to `0px.`

```
<style>
    ul {
        padding: 0;
    }
    li {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding-left: 65px;
    }
    li:hover {
        background: green;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I m glad that helped:)

Answer (score 2):

By removing the margin of the `li` and adding some `padding` to it.

```
li{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 0; /* assuming it had 10px margin first */
    padding-left: 10px; /* more padding */
}
li:hover{
    background: green;
}
```

The only thing that was not allowing it to have background color at the left side was the extra margin. You can also check for the `ul` properties for padding too. It is just an extra spacing.

#### ul was the problem

Ul was also having margin as I said,

so here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/F698P/1/

The CSS added was

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

You can add more padding for the `li` element to make the text go back to where it had to go.

Comment: yes, @Entimon use the ul css too. List is causing the problem here brother.

Comment: ul {  padding: 0;}  use this too.

Comment: @Downvoter, please the reason too! :) That would be helpfull,